# Auth in the Android app via Firebase: Get the user’s first and last name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

There are two rows that can explain the situation:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); //Now user already loggined via Google account
String name = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();//"Walter White"
```

How can we separate the user's name and surname? People can have a couple of words on his name and surname, this way we can't just separate it by space: " ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method in [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) class that can return the first name and the last name, both are returned as a result of a single method call. However, you can create a method to split the entire name in two or more separate names but is not much of a help because you don't know which one is the first name and which one is the last name.

A workaround would be to implement [Firebase authentication with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), where you'll find an interesting class named [GoogleSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount), in which you can find methods like [getFamilyName()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#getFamilyName()) and [getGivenName()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#getGivenName()).